# Saving output from Add Join in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, error-000840

I try to join a polygon layer and a multipoint layer. When the model runs, it keeps saying:

> Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid. ERROR 000840: The value
>   is not a Layer.

How could I solve it?

[image]

Comment: Well looking at your Model and just observing the shadowing the join worked, it's the copy features tool that is failing. So assuming the input is valid it would suggest that the output parameter is invalid. I would suggest double checking that?

Answer (score 2):

The join is not technically a layer in ModelBuilder's mind. I would try adding the 'Make Feature Layer' tool before Copy Features.